# Java: Get Device/Drive Name on Windows

Tags: java, windows, file

I can get a list of drives plugged into a computer with `File.listRoots()`, but I only get the drive letter.  How can I get the actual name of the drive (e.x. "Local Disk", "DVD RW Drive", etc.) as it's shown in Windows Explorer?

Comment: Sorry folks, duplicate.  My bad.

Comment: if you need extra info you can exec "wmic logicaldisk get" and parse it's output

Answer (score 0):

Use `fileSystemView` and the `getSystemDisplayName()`